# I want to sort an list so it contains all values that are not False

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, int64

I have this data:

```
  l = ['10 20 10 36 30 33 400 400 -1 -1', 
       '100 50 50 30 60 27 70 24 -2 -2 700 700', 
       '300 1000 80 21 90 18 100 15 110 12 120 9 900 900 -3 -3',
       '30 90 130 6 140 3 -4 -4 1000 1000']

  l = [e.split() for e in l]

  weight = [int(weight[0]) for weight in l]
```

So i and did the following code:

```
 for data in range(len(weight)):
    if weight[data] < 20 or weight[data] > 200:
        weight[data] = False
        print("Error: Index {:} in weight is out of range".format(data))
```

After my for loop, the weight variable looks like this:

```
  bool [False]
  int  [100]
  bool [False]
  int  [30]
```

I now want to redefine my weight variable, so it contains the values in weight
which are not False:

```
  int  [100]
  int  [30]
```

Comment: you mentioned you wanted to sort the list? is that important?

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
weight = [x for x in weight if x]
```

Better is this because False can be 0 too:

```
weight = [x for x in weight if x is not False]
```

Everything can be done with one list comprehension:

```
weight = [data for data in weight if data < 20 or data > 200]
```

Comment: Safer to use `if x is not False`, because x could be zero.

Comment: Presumably will not work if the desired range is [-10,10] and you have zero weight items.

Comment: You want `weight = [data for data in weight if 20 <= data <= 200]`.

Comment: Thansk for the anwser! But what if i wanted to do the same to an array variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy arrays:

```
arr=np.array(weight)  
weight=arr[arr >0]
```